# order table output based on table itself and different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question, I'm building a forum and I am stuck with the following problem.

I have 2 tables

```
table: topics

topic_id | name    | timestamp           | pinned
-------------------------------------------------
1        | topic_1 | 2016-01-01 12:00:00 | 0
2        | topic_2 | 2016-01-01 13:00:00 | 0
3        | topic_3 | 2016-01-01 14:00:00 | 1
4        | topic_4 | 2016-01-01 15:00:00 | 0
5        | topic_5 | 2016-01-01 16:00:00 | 0

table: messages

message_id | topic_id | text | timestamp
---------------------------------------------------
1          | 1         | test | 2016-01-01 12:30:00
2          | 2         | test | 2016-01-01 13:30:00
3          | 2         | test | 2016-01-01 13:45:00
4          | 1         | test | 2016-01-01 14:30:00
5          | 4         | test | 2016-01-01 17:30:00
```

As you can see, the topic #1 has 2 messages, topic #2 also 2 messages, topic #4 1 messages, topics #3 and #5 no messages at all.

I want to order them on PINNED and TIMESTAMP. How?

-> If a topic is pinned, it MUST BE at the top

-> If the topic has message(s), order them on the timestamp of the LAST message

-> If the topic does not have any messages, order them on the timstamp of the topic itself

Example above, the order would be (from top to bottom):

```
topic_3 (pinned so ALWAYS at the top)
topic_4 (last message at 17:00:00)
topic_5 (no messages but started at 16:00:00)
topic_1 (last message at 14:30:00)
topic_2 (last message at 13:45:00)
```

I hope my question is clear enough.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I tried the following but this won't work

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        t.topic_id,
        t.name 
FROM 
        topics AS t 
LEFT JOIN messages AS m ON m.topic_id = t.topic_id 
ORDER BY 
        t.pinned DESC, 
        m.timestamp DESC,
        t.timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Did you try anything? We expect to see your efforts in solving the problem.

Comment: yes i tried something I will add it to my question

Comment: Improved your code a little bit.

Comment: what did you improved exactly?

Comment: Can you provide an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your database structure and sample date?

Comment: ok will make it now :)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b42ce5 I hope this works, I don't really know how to work with sql fiddle

Comment: looking at the fiddle

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7723f/1 this one is better I think (not sure tho, same result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is complicated by the fact that there are many messages attached to one topic, and you need to use the message having MAX(timestamp) for sorting. `DISTINCT` won't work as it takes a random record out of the table.

I had to use a subquery to solve the problem. `IFNULL` will return message timestamp if it is not NULL, otherwise - topic timestamp as required by the task.

```
SELECT
        t.topic_id,
        t.name,
        IFNULL(m.timestamp, t.timestamp)
FROM 
        topics AS t 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
    messages.topic_id,
    MAX(messages.timestamp) as timestamp
FROM
    messages
GROUP BY
    messages.topic_id
) AS m
  ON m.topic_id = t.topic_id
GROUP BY
      t.topic_id
ORDER BY 
        t.pinned DESC, 
        IFNULL(m.timestamp, t.timestamp) DESC;
```

Output:

```
+----------+---------+----------------------------------+
| topic_id | name    | IFNULL(m.timestamp, t.timestamp) |
+----------+---------+----------------------------------+
|        3 | topic_3 | 2016-01-01 14:00:00              |
|        4 | topic_4 | 2016-01-01 17:30:00              |
|        5 | topic_5 | 2016-01-01 16:00:00              |
|        1 | topic_1 | 2016-01-01 14:30:00              |
|        2 | topic_2 | 2016-01-01 13:45:00              |
+----------+---------+----------------------------------+
```

Remove the timestamp if necessary, I used to show that the query fetches the correct record.

Comment: I was playing around in sqlfiddle and I was getting same outputs without the subselect but with modified ifnull part `IFNULL(MAX(m.timestamp), t.timestamp)`.

Comment: @TheDrot Yeah, I also found it. But decided not to put as an answer as it is a non-standard SQL.

Comment: @user4035... DAMN! you made my day (it works). Thank you very very very much! I was messing with this for 2 days. Thank you, have a nice day!

Comment: @user4035 Ah, ok. I'm not really an SQL guru, at first I was also thinking of subselect, but when it worked without I thought there might be some gotcha with it (ie. wrong results with some datasets).

Comment: @TheDrot Using aggregate functions inside ORDER BY can be a new question. I looked into wikipedia, and it says: "The sort criteria can be expressions, including column names, user-defined functions, arithmetic operations, or CASE expressions."